# PHP For each help please

Tags: php

```
Array (
[item-0] => Array (
    [first-name] => Ahmed
    )
[item-1] => Array (
    [first-name] => Abdelrahman
    )
)
```

Can someone tell me how to return this in a `foreach` loop?

```
foreach($repeater as $val) {
    $data = $val['first-name'];
}
return $data;
```

This only gets the second value, I need both values in the dropdown select menu.

Comment: $data = array();
foreach($repeater as $val) {
    $data[] = $val['first-name'];
}
return $data;

Answer (score 1):

You have to push onto the array, not replace it each time.

```
$data = [];
foreach($repeater as $val) {
    $data[] = $val['first-name'];
}
return $data;
```

But you don't need a loop, you can use the built-in [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
return array_column($repeater, 'first-name');
```